# Error when opening .aj file in Eclipse 22.09 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: eclipse, aspectj

I have installed "AspectJ Development Tools" in eclipse. But when I want to open a ".aj" file, I encounter the following error:

> class org.eclipse.ajdt.core.javaelements.AJCompilationUnit tried to access private field org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.parent (org.eclipse.ajdt.core.javaelements.AJCompilationUnit is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @6c3627c; org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @4faaff61)

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979971/error-when-opening-aj-file-in-sts-4-eclipse-4-21-0) which had a similar problem, but I really didn't get how it was solved. Could any one help me as I am new in Eclipse.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AspectJ read-me for IDE setup](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/master/docs/developer/IDE.md#aspectj-development-tools-ajdt) explains how to install AJDT from a custom update site (not from the Eclipse Marketplace). The one I built for 22.03 should still work on 22.09.